# Many software don't install and installed ones don't open

Tags: windows-10, installation, updates, setup

I am using Dell Inspiron 3593 Windows 10 64 bit

When I try to install Microsoft Teams or any other app I get `Installation has failed`. Checking the setup log I get

```
2021-03-26 11:58:30> Program: Starting Squirrel Updater: --install . --exeName=Teams_windows_x64 (2).exe
2021-03-26 11:58:30> Program: Config already exists. Deleting first.
2021-03-26 11:58:31> Program: setup.json does not exist
2021-03-26 11:58:31> Program: Starting install, writing to C:\Users\Gaurav R Kochar\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp
2021-03-26 11:58:31> Program: File does not contain contextual info: Teams_windows_x64
2021-03-26 11:58:31> UpdateManager: using rootAppDirectory: C:\Users\Gaurav R Kochar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams
2021-03-26 11:58:31> Program: About to install to: C:\Users\Gaurav R Kochar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams
2021-03-26 11:58:31> Program: Setup.json exist, copying over
2021-03-26 11:58:31> RegistryService: RegKeyExists: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run does not have TeamsMachineInstaller
2021-03-26 11:58:31> Program: CheckMsiAndTryAddInstallSource: Not MSI, no need to add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Teams\InstallSource
2021-03-26 11:58:31> CheckForUpdateImpl: Couldn't write out staging user ID, this user probably shouldn't get beta anything: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Gaurav R Kochar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\packages\.betaId'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.WriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding)
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.CheckForUpdateImpl.getOrCreateStagedUserId()
2021-03-26 11:58:31> CheckForUpdateImpl: Failed to load local releases, starting from scratch: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Gaurav R Kochar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\packages\RELEASES'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Squirrel.Utility.LoadLocalReleases(String localReleaseFile)
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.CheckForUpdateImpl.<CheckForUpdate>d__3.MoveNext()
2021-03-26 11:58:31> CheckForUpdateImpl: Reading RELEASES file from C:\Users\Gaurav R Kochar\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp
2021-03-26 11:58:31> CheckForUpdateImpl: First run or local directory is corrupt, starting from scratch
2021-03-26 11:58:31> ApplyReleasesImpl: No delta packages found. Applying current release package.
2021-03-26 11:58:31> ApplyReleasesImpl: getting squirrel aware apps failed with exception Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Gaurav R Kochar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current'.
2021-03-26 11:58:31> ApplyReleasesImpl: Writing files to app directory: C:\Users\Gaurav R Kochar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current
2021-03-26 11:58:34> Unhandled exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The operation was canceled by the user
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.ApplyReleasesImpl.executeSelfUpdate(DirectoryInfo targetDir)
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.ApplyReleasesImpl.<ApplyReleases>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.<FullInstall>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Update.Program.<Install>d__11.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Squirrel.Update.Program.executeCommandLine(String[] args)
   at Squirrel.Update.Program.main(String[] args)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The operation was canceled by the user
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.ApplyReleasesImpl.executeSelfUpdate(DirectoryInfo targetDir)
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.ApplyReleasesImpl.<ApplyReleases>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.<FullInstall>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Update.Program.<Install>d__11.MoveNext()<---

2021-03-26 12:10:31> Program: Starting Squirrel Updater: --install . --exeName=Teams_windows_x64 (2).exe
2021-03-26 12:10:31> Program: Config already exists. Deleting first.
2021-03-26 12:10:31> Program: Starting install, writing to C:\Users\Gaurav R Kochar\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp
2021-03-26 12:10:31> Program: File does not contain contextual info: Teams_windows_x64
2021-03-26 12:10:31> UpdateManager: using rootAppDirectory: C:\Users\Gaurav R Kochar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams
2021-03-26 12:10:31> Program: About to install to: C:\Users\Gaurav R Kochar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams
2021-03-26 12:10:31> Program: Install path C:\Users\Gaurav R Kochar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams already exists, burning it to the ground
2021-03-26 12:10:32> Program: Setup.json exist, copying over
2021-03-26 12:10:32> RegistryService: RegKeyExists: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run does not have TeamsMachineInstaller
2021-03-26 12:10:32> Program: CheckMsiAndTryAddInstallSource: Not MSI, no need to add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Teams\InstallSource
2021-03-26 12:10:32> CheckForUpdateImpl: Couldn't write out staging user ID, this user probably shouldn't get beta anything: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Gaurav R Kochar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\packages\.betaId'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.WriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding)
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.CheckForUpdateImpl.getOrCreateStagedUserId()
2021-03-26 12:10:32> CheckForUpdateImpl: Failed to load local releases, starting from scratch: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Gaurav R Kochar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\packages\RELEASES'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
   at Squirrel.Utility.LoadLocalReleases(String localReleaseFile)
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.CheckForUpdateImpl.<CheckForUpdate>d__3.MoveNext()
2021-03-26 12:10:32> CheckForUpdateImpl: Reading RELEASES file from C:\Users\Gaurav R Kochar\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp
2021-03-26 12:10:32> CheckForUpdateImpl: First run or local directory is corrupt, starting from scratch
2021-03-26 12:10:33> ApplyReleasesImpl: No delta packages found. Applying current release package.
2021-03-26 12:10:33> ApplyReleasesImpl: getting squirrel aware apps failed with exception Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Gaurav R Kochar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current'.
2021-03-26 12:10:33> ApplyReleasesImpl: Writing files to app directory: C:\Users\Gaurav R Kochar\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\current
2021-03-26 12:10:38> Unhandled exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The operation was canceled by the user
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.ApplyReleasesImpl.executeSelfUpdate(DirectoryInfo targetDir)
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.ApplyReleasesImpl.<ApplyReleases>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.<FullInstall>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Update.Program.<Install>d__11.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at Squirrel.Update.Program.executeCommandLine(String[] args)
   at Squirrel.Update.Program.main(String[] args)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The operation was canceled by the user
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.ApplyReleasesImpl.executeSelfUpdate(DirectoryInfo targetDir)
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.ApplyReleasesImpl.<ApplyReleases>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.<FullInstall>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Squirrel.Update.Program.<Install>d__11.MoveNext()<---
```

Also, when I try to open other installed apps like Discord from their shortcut in desktop or from main menu they dont open. I checked that the shortcut was for `update.exe` file and that file doesnt open even if I try to start from there but when I try to open application named app and Discord they both work

How did this problem come and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you recently installed windows? Made any sort of crazy tweaks?

From what it seems, it might be your Anti-virus blocking some 'squirrel' thing from working (**https://discuss.atom.io/t/windows-10-installation-has-failed-error/19833/14**), temporarily disable your Anti-virus.

Searching "squirrel windows 10" yields a bunch of stuff regarding Avast, are you using Avast? That might be causing the problem.

Comment: The windows 10 came directly as part of laptop purchase

Comment: I am using kaspersky antivirus,tried disabling it but still doesnt work